# Delete duplicate rows and keep the newest entry

Tags: powershell, csv

I download a `.csv` file daily which I need to clean up a bit before using it in another software.

The file have data about controls conducted at restaurants, where new controls results in a new row in the file, which means each restaurant can have several entries - I only need the newest.

Here's a portion of the `.csv` file(only included 4 of the columns):

**Headers**

```
orgnummer;navn;dato;total_karakter
```

**4 random rows**

```
985129576;Økern Sushi;21092016;1
785423684;Å cafe;09072017;2
458792365;Varangerkroa;01012018;0
985129576;Økern Sushi;05052018;0
```

`orgnummer` and `navn` will be unique for each restaurant.

In my example the script should remove the top entry of Økern Sushi.

My script so far:

```
$temp = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Downloads\tilsynPS.csv' -Delimiter ';'

#change date format to desired format

foreach($row in $temp) {
    $year = $row.dato.Substring($row.dato.Length - 4, 4)
    $month = $row.dato.Substring($row.dato.Length - 6, 2)
    $day = $row.dato.Substring(0, $row.dato.Length - 6)
    $date = New-Object System.DateTime $year,$month,$day
    $row.dato = $date
}

#Here's my attempt at sorting and deleting old records:

sort orgnummer, dato -Descending

$temp[0]

for ($i=1; $i -le $temp.length -1; $i++)  {
 if ($temp[$i]."orgnummer" -eq $temp[$i-1]."orgnummer"){
   continue
 }
 else {$temp[$i]}

}

#export to csv

$temp | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -path C:\Users\Downloads\tilsynPS_redigert.csv
```

The attempt at removing old records is based on this post: http://community.idera.com/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/powershell_for_windows-12/8073/csv-remove-unique-records-based-on-columns-and-last-date

have also tried with this version of the code:

```
sort -Property @{Expression="dato";Descending=$true},
@{Expression="navn";Descending=$false}

$temp[0]

for ($i=1; $i -le $temp.length -1; $i++)  {
 if ($temp[$i]."navn" -eq $temp[$i-1]."navn"){
   continue
 }
 else {$temp[$i]}

}
```

This is my first script in PowerShell, any help is much appreciated. Have noticed similar questions, but none that are in PowerShell which is what I'm working with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost had it. This solution accumulates the results in a new array and exports that. Rows are only added if the orgnummer is different or the date they hold is newer.

Please note that for testing I had to change the path to the import and export files.

```
$temp = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\tilsynPS.csv" -Delimiter ';'

#change date format to desired format
foreach($row in $temp) {
    $year = $row.dato.Substring($row.dato.Length - 4, 4)
    $month = $row.dato.Substring($row.dato.Length - 6, 2)
    $day = $row.dato.Substring(0, $row.dato.Length - 6)
    $row.dato = New-Object System.DateTime $year,$month,$day
}

# sort on orgnummer and date descending:
$temp = $temp | Sort-Object orgnummer, dato -Descending

# create a new array for the output and add the first entry in it already
$newData = @($temp[0])
# for all other rows in the array, check if they should be added or not
for ($i = 1; $i -le $temp.Length -1; $i++)  {
    if ($temp[$i]."orgnummer" -eq $temp[$i-1]."orgnummer" -and $temp[$i]."dato" -le $temp[$i-1]."dato") {
        continue
    }
    else { 
        $newData += $temp[$i] 
    }
}

#export to csv
$newData | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -path "$PSScriptRoot\tilsynPS_redigert.csv"
```

Comment: p.s. to convert the 'dato' strings in the csv you could also use `$row.dato = [DateTime]::ParseExact($row.dato, 'ddMMyyyy', $null)`

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that. I had some trouble finding a way to convert the dato field, since it has a strange/unconsistent format in the .csv . Mostly it is written with ddmmyyyy, but there are discrepancies, meaning that some entries are written dmmyyyy, missing the first "0".

Comment: Hi Einar, in that case i would do this: `$row.dato = [DateTime]::ParseExact(('{0:D8}' -f [int]$row.dato), 'ddMMyyyy', $null)`, just to make sure a leading zero is added to those cases